# Latched topic in ZeroMQ

Tags: python, c++, zeromq

Is it possible to have a "latched" topic in ZeroMQ, such that the last message sent to the topic is repeated to newly joined subscribers?

At the moment I have to create a **`REQ-REP`**-socket pair in addition to the **`PUB-SUB`** pair, so that when the new **`SUB`** joins, it asks for that last message using the **`REQ`**-socket. But this additional work, which is all boilerplate, is highly undesirable.

[**`ROS`**](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) has the "latched" option and it is described as:

> When a connection is latched, the last message published is saved and
>   automatically sent to any future subscribers that connect. This is
>   useful for slow-changing to static data like a map. Note that if there
>   are multiple publishers on the same topic, instantiated in the same
>   node, then only the last published message from that node will be
>   sent, as opposed to the last published message from each publisher on
>   that single topic.

Answer (score 1):

### Well, your idea is doable in ZeroMQ:

Given a few bits from history, where due to a distributed-computing performance and memory capacity reasons and low costs of traffic, the topic-filter was initially implemented on the **`SUB`**-side(s), whereas later versions started to operate this feature on the **`PUB`**-side.

So, you application will never know in advance, which clients will use which version of the ZeroMQ and the problem is principally un-decidable.

Having this said,
your application user-code, on the **`PUB`**-side, can solve this, sending 2-in-1 formatted messages, and your **`SUB`**-side can be made aware of this soft-logic embedded into the message-stream.

Simply implement the "latched" logic in your user-code, be it via a naive re-send of each message per topic-line or some other means.

---

### Yes, the very user-code is the only one, who can handle this,

not the **`PUB/SUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetype -- for two reasons -- it is not any general, universally applicable behaviour, but rather a user-specific speciality -- plus -- the topic-filter ( be it **`PUB`**-side or **`SUB`**-side operated ) has no prior knowledge about lexical-branching ( subscriptions are lexically interpreted from the left to the right and no one can a-priori say, what will a next subscriber actually subscribe to, and thus a "latched"-last-message store will not be able to get pre-populated until a new "next" subscriber actually joins and sets its actual topic-filter subscription ( storing all deterministic, combinatorics driven, possible {sub-|super-}-topic options is a very bad idea to circumvent the principal undecidability, isn't it? ) )